# Ubuntu login fails with a user of a trusted IDM domain (AD)

Tags: active-directory, samba4, ubuntu-20.04, trust-relationship, rocky-linux

We have an IDM Server on a Rocky Linux distro configured with a Trust to a Samba AD DC (also installed on a Rocky Linux).

So we created a user 'usupru2' on Samba AD DC under adtest.uy domain.

Then we enroll an Ubuntu 20.04 client to IDM and when we try to login with 'usupru2@adtest.uy' it fails with the message below:

```
Dec  2 18:05:30 prueba gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost= 
Dec  2 18:05:30 prueba gdm-password]: pam_sss(gdm-password:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost= user=usupru2@ADTEST.UY
Dec  2 18:05:30 prueba gdm-password]: pam_sss(gdm-password:auth): received for user usupru2@ADTEST.UY: 10 (User not known to the underlying authentication module)
```

Executing id usupru2@adtest.uy does not work, but kinit does.

On IDM server login with usupru2@adtest.uy works.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this error was that the group (GID) assigned to the user (on creation) didn't exist. So we created it on Samba and now its working properly.